# How to configure my theme in Magento ver. 2.1.1?

Tags: magento, backend, magento2

I have installed  Magento version - 2.1.1 in my local but can't see any option to define my theme in back-end please review attached screenshot.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPCmq.png]

Any one have Idea ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To apply a theme:

In Admin,

1) go to Content >Configuration > Design.

2) Click on **Edit** link of Global.

3) Select your Theme From **Drop Down** of **Applied Theme** And Save.

4) If caching is enabled, clear the cache.

5) run php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy command in shell.

6) To see your changes applied, reload the store front pages.

This is new Setting in **Magento 2.1**

[image]You can try to set theme using following steps

Answer (score 0):

Hello Currently I have only one store please review attached screenshot

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/9nhdl.png]

Comment: Any one have idea ?

Comment: Hello,

I am getting below error :

Cannot read contents from file "D:/wamp64/www/magento2.1.1/" Warning!file_get_contents(D:/wamp64/www/magento2.1.1/): failed to open stream: No such file or directory